# Java think Radio button is always selected

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

I have a program which should display the price 1.50 * the number of radio buttons except my program doesn't recognize the radio button is on thus doesn't display the 1.50.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author silve
 */
public class Page3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Page3
     */
    public Page3() {
        initComponents();


      double Checkout1 = RadioBtn();

        double Lj = Checkout1 * 1.50;

        String LM = String.valueOf(Lj);

        ToppingsPriceL.setText((LM) + "0");  


    }
public double RadioBtn() {
    double Checkout = 0;



   if(GreenOlivesBtn.isSelected()) {
        Checkout++; 
    }

   return Checkout;



}
```

Comment: `rb.setSelected(b)` Sets selected status of a radio button to b (true/false).

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you're calling `RadioBtn()` on gui creation when it is almost guaranteed not to be selected. In order for this code to work, the method needs to be called within a listener of some sort, perhaps an ActionListener, since the user needs to have the opportunity to change the state of the radio button and then the GUI responds to this.

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Comment: How would I do this exactly can you give me an example

Comment: @k_gg9: no, that would be cheating you out of the opportunity to create your own code. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) -- check out how to use ActionListeners and JButtons in the tutorials. Good luck.